# Solving a second order PDE with only one second derivative term

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

I am interested in solving a differential equation of the form

$$a\,\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2} + by\,\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + cy\,\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}+itf = 0$$

for $f=f(x,y)$, with $a$, $b$, $c$ and $t$ constant, and boundary condition $f(x_0,y) = 1$, and the other boundary term left general. If a second boundary condition is required, I am interested in conditions of the form $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x} (x_1,y) = 0$.

Since there is only a second derivative in one of the variables, I thought it might be tractable, but I have tried the method of characteristics and couldn't find get the equation into a form I could solve.

Are there some clever tricks to solve differential equations of this form?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure it's $by\,\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and not $bx\,\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}?$

Comment: Yes, it is definitely $by\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$.